# Making WCF service run over HTTP with simple user config based authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

I've looked up and down and I can't seem to find a way to have a simple WCF service (with either `basicHttpBinding` or `wsHttpBinding`) authenticate against this sort of config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies">
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
      <user name="test" password="pass"/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

Basically, I want to hardcode a simple user/pass (don't ask why) and make sure my WCF service uses this.

On the client side I have this:

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pass";
```

But the credentials do not seem to get passed on. The `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` is never authenticated on the WCF side.

I've tried playing with the settings below trying to use everything from None, Transport, Message... but only `None` seems to let the service run (but no credentials are being sent/used). Other settings seem to require a X509 certificate (as I've found out in [this great example](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2010/03/22/a-simple-wcf-service-with-username-password-authentication-the-things-they-don-t-tell-you/)).

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="userHttp">
      <security mode="None">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

So, all in all... I want to create a very simple WCF service (that runs over HTTP - not HTTPS) with even simpler plain text username/password authentication. Should be possible but I am already lost. The best solution involves honoring `<user />` entries but I'd be happy with any other simple implementation. It doesn't need to use cookies. As far as I am concerned it may as well send username/password on each service method call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send user/pass in the message level without ssl then use [ClearUsernameBinding](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html). If you want the same in the transport level then use [TransportCredentialOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648505.aspx).

```
<binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
</binding>
```